# How to respond to text message with Django/Twilio

Tags: python, django, twilio

I set up a page "example.com/firstsms" to send a SMS through Twilio and redirect to the homepage. If I then use the phone to respond to the message I want to reply with a confirmation. As of now, nothing happens.

In urls.py I have:

```
(r'^hellomonkey/$', 'crusher.views.HelloMonkey'),
```

In views.py I tried to adapt their [Flask example](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/hello-monkey):

```
def HelloMonkey(request):
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.sms("Hello, Mobile Monkey") 
    return HttpResponseRedirect(str(resp), content_type="text/plain")
```

Racking my brain! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a `HttpResponseRedirect` so it would try to redirect to some page and of course it doesn't work. You should use `HttpResponse` instead:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def HelloMonkey(request):
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""

    resp = twilio.twiml.Response()
    resp.sms("Hello, Mobile Monkey") 
    return HttpResponse(str(resp))
```

Comment: Thanks! I've tried to create conditional responses and started another question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986721/conditional-sms-response-with-django-twilio)

Answer (score 2):

Devangelist from Twilio here, I've been maintaining the Django-twilio library and there is a much easier solution to responding to SMS and Voice with Twilio.

First, [pip install django-twilio and get it set up using the instructions here](http://django-twilio.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html).

Then in your view you can use the `twilio_view` decorator like so:

```
from django_twilio.decorators import twilio_view
from twilio.twiml import Response    

@twilio_view
def my_view(request):
    r = Response()
    r.message('Hello, world!')
    return r
```

Django-twilio will handle the correct HTTPResponse stuff for you, as well as ensure the request is coming from a genuine twilio.com source.