# Conditional SMS response with Django/Twilio

Tags: python, django, twilio

I'm trying to adjust the SMS response depending on different parameters (caller id, body of text) and the error is "HTTP retrieval failure"
I've tried using the Flask tutorial for different callers:

```
def hello_monkey():
    """Respond and greet the caller by name."""

    from_number = request.values.get('From', None)
    if from_number in callers:
        message = callers[from_number] + ", thanks for the message!"
    else:
        message = "Monkey, thanks for the message!"
```

But I realize Django might be different, so I've tried these and a couple others:

```
def hello_monkey(request, From)
    #with    
    from = From

def hello_monkey(request):
    #with
    number = request.POST["Body"]
```

Thanks
Edit: forgot the [link](http://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/python/sms/replying-to-sms-messages)

Comment: Did the Flask tutorial work?

Comment: Curiously enough, I couldn't figure out flask database stuff so I went with Django. I'm sure Flask works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually in Django it would be quite similar, you should read more about the [request](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/). Since you don't know if the request is POST or GET, you can take in use of `HttpRequest.REQUEST`:

```
callers = {
    "+14158675309": "Curious George",
    "+14158675310": "Boots",
    "+14158675311": "Virgil",
}

def hello_monkey(request):
    """Respond and greet the caller by name."""

    from_number = request.REQUEST.get('From', None)
    if from_number in callers:
        message = callers[from_number] + ", thanks for the message!"
    else:
        message = "Monkey, thanks for the message!"

    # .... your code ....
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks so much! in case anyone was wondering, this REQUEST.get() also works if you replace 'From' with 'Body'

Comment: You're welcome. Basically `request.REQUEST` is a dict so you can use `get()` http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get normally. Just ping me if you have any other question ;)

Comment: It depends on Twilio backend and since in the example the view should receive both GET and POST so I wouldn't bet on that. Using REQUEST is the safe choice for you.